# How to download a website's html source automatically

Tags: html, web-crawler

Does anybody know of any program where I can enter a domain name, and the program will crawl the entire domain and be able to download all of the HTML source code for me - so if the site has links on the page, it will crawl only to the pages on the domain name, not to external domain names obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at scrapy for python:

http://www.scrapy.org

or crawler4j for java:

http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/

Comment: Thank you...do you know of any good c# ones that I could also try perchance?